# Java AES Encryption/Decryption using a BigInteger as a key

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, biginteger

Is it possible to encrypt/decrypt a string using AES with a BigInteger (given one, not a randomly generated number) as a key in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need BigInteger for AES key creation, the key needs to be 16 bytes long for 128-bit encryption, 24 bytes long for 192-bit encryption and 32 bytes long for 256-bit encryption.

So the key would be a byte array rather than a BigInteger. BigInteger is used in RSA and other PKI's because of the huge numbers needed to create the keys but AES doesn't do that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and BigIntegers can be byte arrays :)

Comment: Thanks for this, you gave me a clue to generate a key :)

+1